# Restrict file browsing to a specific path only

Tags: html, file, input

is there any way to restrict file browsing to a specific path?

```
<input type="file" name="pic" >
```

the path may or may not be in local file system, it can also be in network or any other location.

is it possible to do this?

i am using JSP+struts 1.x

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the location of the file due to security reasons.

But you can limit the accepted file types by setting a accept attribute with a mime-type on the input element.

```
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" />
```

See the [input element specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#file-select):

```
accept = content-type-list [CI]
 This attribute specifies a comma-separated list of content types that a server
 processing this form will handle correctly. User agents may use this information
 to filter out non-conforming files when prompting a user to select files to be sent
 to the server (cf. the INPUT element when type="file").
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot. Web server cannot have that privilege to do such a restriction on user local file system. If anyone can do this, I treat this as a hacking.